# Fragment not added (inconsistent crash)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

In my `MainActivity`, I have:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    checkForCrashes();
    checkForTutorial();
    checkForUpdates();
    setStore();
    setup();
}
```

In `setup()`, I call `initializeTabs()` in a callback:

```
protected void setup() {
    final Store s = getStore();
    setBackground();

    if (s == null) {
        unauthorizedHandler();
        return;
    }
    final Context mainActivity = this;
    fragments = getTabFragments();

    StoresController.getStoreDetails(s, mainActivity, new Callback<StoreDetailDecorator>() {
        @Override
        public void success(StoreDetailDecorator storeDetailDecorator, Response response) {
            s.prettyName = storeDetailDecorator.store.pretty_name;
            s.save();
            Log.v(TAG, s.prettyName);
            TextView toolbar_label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_label);
            toolbar_label.setText(MainActivity.getTruncatedMenuName(s.name()));

            SummaryTab t1 = (SummaryTab)fragments.get(0);
            t1.notifier = (SummaryTabLoadingNotifier)mainActivity;
            initializeTabs(s, fragments);
            t1.populateReport();
        }
    }
}

public void initializeTabs(Store s, List<Fragment> fragments ) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getTabTitles(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

That last line is crashing for some customers.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment InfoTab{1bcb80f} is not currently in the FragmentManager
```

But not every time. Why would this happen sometimes? Something to do with the fragment not being connected? I read some things about checking `isAdded()` on a fragment, but that's for checking if a fragment is added to an Activity. I'm using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private CharSequence[] titles;
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, CharSequence titles[], List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.titles = titles;
        this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { return titles[position]; }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return fragmentList.size(); }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Could `saveState(){ return null;}` be it? This is there, as I understand things, to ensure the view is refreshed every time.

Comment: similar to your question nice and clear answer is here > http://stackoverflow.com/a/11296700/5188159

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onResume()` is called every time your activity returns to foreground.

If one of your users, for example, presses the home button and returns to your app then `getStoreDetails()` will be called again and you'll create a new adapter (with the same old fragment list) when the result arrives.

You should instantiate your fragments, create an adapter and populate your `viewpager` with the adapter only once (`onCreate()` would be the spot).

When new data arrives from `getStoreDetails()` just update the already added fragments with the new data.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are returning `null` in `saveState()`. You shouldn't try to override this behavior.
But even if you want to do it for some reason, you have to override `public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader)` as well to avoid crash, because that method is relying on data saved in `saveState()`.

But I would suggest you to not override it at all, and instead explain what you wanted to achieve there.